# Implementing "TYPE A" in an FTP server

Tags: c++, qt, ftp, ftp-server

I'm writing an FTP server (in Qt/C++), and right now I with "200 Ok" to "TYPE A", but I really treat it the same as "TYPE I" - files are sent as-is.

How should I go about properly implementing TYPE A? Would opening the files in text mode instead of binary mode be enough?

Also, I assume that the SIZE method should be more complex than returning the file's size on disk, it should read it and perform the text substitutions, and return the size that way?

**Edit:** In response to a comment, here's the relevant excerpt from [the RFC959 spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt):

> ```
>      3.1.1.1.  ASCII TYPE
>
>         This is the default type and must be accepted by all FTP
>         implementations.  It is intended primarily for the transfer
>         of text files, except when both hosts would find the EBCDIC
>         type more convenient.
>
>         The sender converts the data from an internal character
>         representation to the standard 8-bit NVT-ASCII
>         representation (see the Telnet specification).  The receiver
>         will convert the data from the standard form to his own
>         internal form.
>
>         In accordance with the NVT standard, the <CRLF> sequence
>         should be used where necessary to denote the end of a line
>         of text.  (See the discussion of file structure at the end
>         of the Section on Data Representation and Storage.)
>
>         Using the standard NVT-ASCII representation means that data
>         must be interpreted as 8-bit bytes.
>
>         The Format parameter for ASCII and EBCDIC types is discussed
>         below.
> ```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'I return success for "TYPE A"'? What do you mean by "How should I go about properly implementing TYPE A"? Your question currently assumes too much knowledge that is in your head, but not in others' like mine. ;)

Comment: That's how the commands are named. You write "TYPE A" in the control connection to specify ASCII, and "TYPE I" stands for Image - meaning binary.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: sure there is: At RFC959 page 27 are the types A (ASCII), I (Image) and E (EBCDIC) described.

Comment: @sashoalm: the standard only has ascii type, not "a" type, but feel free to point "type a" out in the standard.

Comment: @LaszloPapp They're listed in "REPRESENTATION TYPE (TYPE)", but yes, it's not easy to find. But if you open an FTP client, they usually log the control connection, you'll see it there.

Comment: And that is what I meant by knowledge assumption. I would argue if it was crystal clear. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For transferring files with ASCII mode (type A) you would need to open the files in text mode and then transfer them with line ending CRLF. If you implement the SIZE command you would be required to report the size according to the transfer type. Because this is obviously too much overhead to scan the whole file just for getting the size right server often return `550 SIZE not allowed in ASCII mode` if the command is used not in image mode.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, I was too lazy, it seems, because when I finally when around to finding the excerpt, it was all there. I guess the site helped as a rubber duck here :)